# chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I'm getting the above error when running `composer install --working-dir=/path/to/directory`

In case you're wondering: I had a hard drive failure so I needed to re-install composer and well... everything. After installing composer, navigating to the directory with the `composer.json` file and running `composer install` would result in an error that composer couldn't find a `composer.json` file, hence the `--working-dir` flag.

The project is a Laravel 4.2 project. We have everything in a git repo with the exception of the vendor folder. We figured we would just run `composer install` and all would be right in the world - and it was.

I ran `composer install --verbose` and received the following:

```
Exception trace:
 () at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:149
 Composer\Util\ErrorHandler::handle() at n/a:n/a chdir() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:149
 Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/Console/Application.php:83
 Composer\Console\Application->run() at phar://C:/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar/bin/composer:43
 require() at C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar:25
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Not sure why I'm suddenly having these problems. A week or two ago a co-worker was able to run all of the same steps without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the main problem was the starting directory of gitbash.

When I installed it, I changed the starting directory to be `c:\users\[me]\My Documents`

Even though this directory had sub-directories, and I could `cd` into them; running an `ls` would produce 0 results.

I ended up changing the starting directory to `c:\users\[me]\Documents` and everything worked fine. Composer found the `composer.json` file and all other commands worked. Lesson learned.