# lumen: [ErrorException] chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

**UPDATED:**

I transfer the contents of the `public` folder to the root and transferred the contents of `root` folder to the `lara` folder like this:

[image]

When i run:

```
php artisan serve
```

this error comming:

> [ErrorException]
>     chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

**What have I done?**

I try these solutions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35047783/9422637), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28698381/9422637) but no solution found.

I use from this server:

> PHP 7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

Also I use from `Lumen` instead of `Laravel`.

*Thanks for sharing your knowledge*

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your public folder is available..

Comment: Indeed as I thought you renamed the public folder. Please see [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30350933/using-artisan-serve-after-changing-the-public-folder-name[/link]

Comment: Do I see right you put the complete laravel folder under a web root??